# How to shorten or remove the "tick marks" below a BarChart?

Tags: ticks, charts

I am trying to make those downward "tick marks" below the horizontal axis of a `BarChart` shorter or removed. They look very crowded in a figure like the following one. How can I do that?

[image]

Here is the code to produce the figure:

```
n = Range[10];
dat1 = 1/n^2;
dat2 = 0.9 dat1;
dat = {dat1, dat2};
sty = {Orange, Black};

SetOptions[BarChart, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 8}, 
  AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0.5], LabelStyle -> Black];
SetOptions[Labeled, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 8}];

pic = Labeled[
  BarChart[Transpose@dat, ChartStyle -> {Orange, Black}, 
   BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, 
   ChartLabels -> {Placed[n, Above, Style[#, FontSize -> 8] &], None},
    AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 225], {"Horizontal Axis", 
   "Vertical Axis"}, {Bottom, Left}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the tick lengths are hard-coded, so the only way to fix the lengths is to post-process the graphics output. Since the ticks have the form `Line[{a, Offset[b, c]}]`, you can use:

```
pic /. Line[{a_, Offset[b_, c_]}] :> Line[{a, Offset[b/2, c]}]
```

[image]

to cut the length of the ticks in half. If you want to remove them entirely, you could use:

```
pic /. Line[{a_, Offset[b_, c_]}] :> Sequence[]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Carl Woll. This works perfect. Can you explain a little bit what are the parameters `a`, `b`, and `c` in `Line[{a, Offset[b, c]}]`? To remove the ticks, why `Sequence[]` is needed instead of just changing `b` to 0?

Answer (score 1):

This is not precisely an answer to the question. I find `BarChart` to be particularly unwieldy. It's not that much trouble to reproduce the figure using `Graphics`, allowing easy control of all the elements.

```
Show[
 Plot[{}, {x, 0, Length[dat1]}, PlotRange -> {0, Max[dat] + .1}],
 Graphics[{
   Table[{Orange, EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{n - 1, 0}, {n - .6, dat1[[n]]}], 
          Black, Rectangle[{n - .6, 0}, {n - .2, dat2[[n]]}]}, {n, Length[dat1]}],
   Table[Text[n, {n - .6, Max[Transpose[dat][[n]]] + .05}], {n, Length[dat1]}]
   }], 
 AspectRatio -> .5, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 10}, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic},
 FrameLabel -> {"Horizontal Axis", "Vertical Axis"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those marks aren't ticks; they are data set grouping indicators. They are intended to help the viewer associate the label with data group that it labels. I do not know how to eliminate them, but certain plot themes draw them above the x-axis rather than below. You may find that more acceptable.

For example:

```
Labeled[
  BarChart[Transpose@dat,
    PlotTheme -> "Web",
    BaseStyle -> {"TR", 8},
    ChartStyle -> {Orange, Black},
    BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, 
    ChartLabels -> {Placed[n, Above, Style[#, FontSize -> 8] &], None}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/2,
    ImageSize -> 300],
  Style[#, "TR", 10] & /@ {"Horizontal Axis", "Vertical Axis"},
  {Bottom, Left},
  RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image: plot]