# How to make a bar graph like this?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions, charts

I've read some article recently and because I've been doing the same calculations so far, I wanted to have a graph like this: [image]

by the looks of it, it certainly looks like it was done in mathematica, as you can see at each natural number n, it is split into 3 domains for the different colors, this is very useful as it shows the interference.

Comment: does [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113907/125) give what you need?

Answer (score 2):

`BarChart` accepts lists of lists; each sublist is a single datapoint from each data set.  For instance `BarChart@Table[{i,i,i},{i,20}]` gives

[image: basic]

So a rough attempt at that chart is

```
BarChart[{(8^# E^-8)/#!,(12^# E^-12)/#!,(16^# E^-17)/#!}&/@Range@30,
  ChartStyle->{Blue,Yellow,Green}]
```

[image: rough]

In my mind there are two ways to refine this to make it "right": get the data right, and get the style right.

If you have the equations, getting the data right is easy.  If not, it's surprisingly easy to derive the data from the image (with Mathematica).  It may even be useful to do curve fitting (which is, again, easy with Mathematica).

Matching the above style is hard.  Here's some options that need to be specified (I don't know exactly how to do them)

- bar black outlines
- spacing between bar triplets
- ticks along entire frame
- ticks are in the style of a graph (not divisions between bars, but axes)
- font

Hopefully you can go from here!

Comment: the problem with barcharts is that they don't start from 0 in the conventional x axis, is there any way to get around this?

Comment: If you want to stick with bar chart labels it's easy; wrap each datum in a `Labeled` with the appropriate number.  It looks like `BarChart` isn't the best way to do this, though; see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198975/how-to-shorten-or-remove-the-tick-marks-below-a-barchart.  Probably removing the bottom ticks a la Carl Woll's answer and `Show`ing a `Plot` along with is better